# Symfony2 file manager

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, file-manager, file-browser

I am looking for Symfony2 bundle(s) which provide file manager functionality:

- create directories and sub-directories
- upload files

and then in form for "file" field type elements I would need to choose from the files uploaded using file manager to provide file browser functionality.

I have found several bundles that provide file manager options like https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle which fits my needs but haven`t found any file manager + file browser for forms.

Is there anything like that available? Or maybe something(separate file manager and separate file browser) that can be "tied" together manually?

Comment: Voting to close. This isn’t a programming problem.

Answer (score 3):

take a look into [TreeBrowserBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/bundles/tree_browser/introduction.html)